# JavaScript: Read directory from within addEventListener function

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, fs

I added an event listener to my website which should add a date, time and device-id to the website. These information are included in the filenames of some files located in a directory at the same level as my index.html.
Directory Structure:
- audiofiles
-- date_time_device.wav
-- date2_time2_device2.wav
- scripts
-- scripts.js
- Home.html

Within the head of Home.html I'm calling a addContent() (located in scripts.js) which includes the addEventListener().
This works if I'm inserting hardcoded strings, so it seems that reading from the directory does not work.
It would be great if anybody could steer me into the right direction. Thanks!

Head of Home.html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='scripts/scripts.js'> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/wavesurfer.js"></script>
    <script>
        addContent();
    </script>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
```

scripts.js:

```
function addContent() {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        var fs = require('fs');
        const files = fs.readdirSync('path/to/audiofiles');

        for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
            var date = files[i].slice(0,10);
            var time = files[i].slice(11,19);
            var device = files[i].slice(20,-4);

            var TheInnerHTML ="";
            TheInnerHTML += "<tr><td> blabla" + 3 + " " + String(date)+"</td><td>"+String(time)+"</td></tr>"+String(device)+"</td></tr><br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("TheBody").innerHTML = TheInnerHTML;
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using `fs` to access files *on the client* or are you trying to read from the *server*?

Comment: I'm running this locally on my laptop. All files and subdirectories are located in the same directory on my local machine.

Comment: you cannot directly access the file system from the browser. The code fragment you are using is from nodejs which should be executed on server.

Comment: thanks. is there another way to do what I want to accomplish?